# Can I connect this IPS display to a Raspberry Pi (or any SBC for that matter)

Tags: raspberry-pi, display

[image: 640 x 480 IPS display with a 30 pin, 05mm pitch flex cable at the end of it]
Can I use this display with a Raspberry Pi or any other SBC? It's a 640 x 480 IPS display with a 30 pin, 05mm pitch flex cable at the end of it. I've been trying to look for a connector or something but I'm coming up with nothing. (could this work? https://www.twoyas.com/products/chang-edp-to-hdmi-adapter-board)

Comment: You need significant details about the pinout -- which pins are display data, which are backlight power, which are touchscreen.  They aren't standard and getting it wrong has the potential to damage either or both the device and the display (largely because backlight pins will be much higher voltage than data pins)

Comment: @BenVoigt It came from a cheap Chinese emulation handheld. I tried looking for the exact model with the manufacturer but couldn't find it. Am I going to just have to buy a new display?

Comment: You can try reverse engineering (which should be done while you still have a functioning control device)

Comment: I really don't think I myself would be able to do that... plus the control device doesn't really want to boot up at all. I stripped a lot of the parts off of it.

Comment: You can try to trace the connections either back through the control PCB (easier, since you've already disassembled that) or forward through the display PCB (which you probably only have access to one side without destroying the nice bezel)

Comment: Overall it's not worth it for quantity 1.  Spend a few extra (insert currency of choice) to get a display from an engineering vendor who provides proper documentation.  If you had a stack of dozens of returns, the tradeoff would be different.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not very good at reading PCBs. I have it with me fully disassembled but I doubt I'll be able to make any sense of it at my current knowledge level.

Comment: Yup. Thanks, probably will end up doing that.

Comment: Just wanted to see what I could do since the bezel and screen itself was really nice.